Compile Octave 9.1 API on windows via Visual Studio 2022
So i would like to use Octave 9.1 API in my C++ code in Visual Studio 2022.
To perform it i need the correct .lib and .dll files.
I try to search a precompiled version of it or a step by step tutorial to make the .lib and .dll files.
